# AngularJS directive calling a callback function

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying make a dropdownlist directive, and I want it to have an attribute like `onItemSelected="myCallbackFunction(selectedItem)"`, how can I do it? Can someone provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `&` binding (Isolate Scope Function Expression Binding)

```
.directive("sample", [function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            myFunc: "&"
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.myFunc(); //whenever you wanna call it
        }
   }
}])
```

And the HTML

```
<div sample my-func="someScopeFunction()"></div>
```

Id recommend reading: https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750 for directive binding explanations.

Answer (score 0):

To complement tymeJV's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270360/angularjs-directive-calling-a-callback-function/31270447#31270447), if you are not using isolate scope you can make use of `$eval` or `$parse`.

```
app.directive('sample', function($parse){
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    link:function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      $parse(attrs.evt)(scope);

      scope.$eval(attrs.eval);
    }
  };
});
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/P1hggqBXMBKBMqJtr6Zg?p=preview